# SEO: Can bots see php code using variables?

Tags: php, seo

If html, in this case an alt tag,  is written via php, which takes the values of two database fields, puts them into variables and then displays them with echo, can bots see the values of the alt tags as they are displayed in the browser or as the code is here?

```
echo (...... alt=\"".$fld['name'] . " " . $fld['description']."\".....)
```

I mean, if name = "apples" and description = "red and juicy"

do the search bots see alt = "apples red and juicy" or the code above?

I suspect its the code.

Comment: Bots see the rendered HTML, not the PHP

Comment: Bots will see `apples red and juicey`, not the code. The PHP is rendered server side. Bots see exactly what you would see by accessing the page (minus JavaScript manipulation if the bot doesn't support JavaScript). If you can see it, the bot can see it. The only way for the code to show is if you serve the page with an incorrect mime type preventing the server from executing the code.

Answer (score 2):

The search engines see exactly what your browser see's. So in your example the code name="apples" and description="red and juicy" will be what the search engine sees.

This only applies to server side code (such as PHP). JavaScript code is sent to the browser along with the HTML and is executed client side by the browser.

There may be a case where, due to a misconfigured server your PHP pages will be served as text. If you load the page in your browser and use the browser "view source" option you can see exactly what is being sent to the browser.

Comment: Excluding the javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I've added another paragraph

Comment: So just to be clear, the server loads the variables from the database and displays the loaded content and the bots see the value of the variables not the php variables? The words "name" and "description" shouldn't display, it would just be the values ie alt = "apples red and juicy". yes?

Comment: That's correct. If you want to see for yourself load the page in your web browser and use the "view source" browser option. This will show you the HTML that the browser/search engines see.

Comment: OK, that's easy. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the output of the PHP into HTML, so:

```
<... alt="apples red and juicy"/>
```

would be read by the bot because they parse the HTML of a page. The PHP is processed into HTML on the server side, so the `$fld` hash, and therefore `$fld['name']`/`$fld['description']` is invisible to a search bot.

Comment: Don't you mean "is invisible to a search bot"?